# How to set nuget package version using build number with nugetter

Tags: nuget

We're using nugetter to make a nupkg as part of our build process for a solution that only builds occasionally, and that we want to distribute in the future. We also want to use this package in other solutions we have.  So far, I've been able to generate a package that we can install.  Now, I want to be sure that this package updates its version every time it's built so we can update the package easily.  I'm thinking that using the build number would be a good way to do this, but I'd be willing to use just about any incrementing scheme if I don't have to start writing a powershell script to update the nuspec for package on every build.

Is there a way to do this automatically in nugetter?

If not, is there something easier than modifying the nuspec with powershell?

Answer (score 0):

We're trying to do the same thing. NuGetter ships with a build process template that builds on top of TfsVersioning. Are you using that already? If so, all you have to do is add a special element for your NuGet package ID to the `VersionSeed.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<VersionSeed>
  <Solution name="Your Solution Name">
    <!-- This is the pattern used to replace the AssemblyVersion value. -->
    <AssemblyFileVersionPattern>1.0.J.B</AssemblyFileVersionPattern>
    <!-- This is the pattern used to replace the AssemblyVersion value. -->
    <AssemblyVersionPattern>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersionPattern>
  </Solution>
  <NuGetPackage id="Your NuGet Package ID">
    <!-- This is the pattern used to replace the version attribute in the NuSpec file. -->
    <VersionPattern>1.0.J.B</VersionPattern>
  </NuGetPackage>
</VersionSeed>
```

It's not a very well documented NuGetter feature, but it's in their help file somewhere.

Also, you still have to set the `<version>` attribute in the NuSpec file. Currently, I force it to 0.0.0.0 because it is overridden by the build process anyway. Removing the `<version>` element completely seems to always result in a crash.